# Homsets of group actions related to fixed points

Tags: group-actions

MacLane and Moerdijk's [Sheaves in Geometry and Logic](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SGwwDerbEowC&dq=mac+lane+moerdijk&source=gbs_navlinks_s) has a section on Continuous Group Actions (Sec. III.9).  On page 152, there is an isomorphism displayed:

$$Hom_G(G/U, X) \cong X^U$$

In their set-up, $G$ is a topological group, $U$ is an open subgroup, $X$ is a set (space with discrete topology) with an action of $G$.  The Hom-set is that of right G-actions.  $X^U$ is the set of $U$-fixed points in $X$.  (This result probably holds for ordinary groups instead of topological groups.  I can't say.)  The commentary following the display says "as usual" by which, they presumably mean it is widely known.  But I can't find anything like it in the standard text books.

Can somebody figure out what this isomorphism is?  Or, tell me where to look to find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G/U$ has a distinguished element, namely the coset of the identity. A $G$-morphism $G/U \to X$ is completely determined by where it sends this coset, and the possible points in $X$ it can be sent to are precisely points fixed by the action of $U$. (This should make sense on the point-set level, and then one only has to check that the topological details work out.)

One way of describing this result is that $G$ is the free $G$-set on a point and $G/U$ is the free $G$-set on a $U$-fixed point.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks very much.  I was probably too exhausted to understand it last night.  But, I had chat with an 'expert' this morning, who made it all clear to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with $\hom_G(G, X) \cong X$? Composing with the map $\hom_G(G/U, X) \to \hom_G(G, X)$ (which is monic!) gives you the injection $\hom_G(G/U, X) \to X$ you seek.